# Tooltip on form field not showing in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, tooltip, angular-directive

I Created a directive for form input field in my controller named AppCtrl

```
angular.module('app').directive('inputTooltip', function($timeout, $compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

          var formCtrl = controllers[0],
          ngModelCtrl = controllers[1];
          console.log(formCtrl);
          function trigger() {
              $timeout(function() {
                  element.trigger('manual');
              }, 0);
          };

          var name = element[0].name;

          attrs.$set('tooltipTrigger', 'focus');
          attrs.$set('tooltipPlacement', 'bottom');
          attrs.$set('tooltipEnable', formCtrl.$name + '.' + name + '.$invalid');
          attrs.$set('tooltip', 'Please Enter Valid Value');

          ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(trigger);

          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          $(element).tooltip('show');
      }
  };
});
```

and the HTML element is

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : settingsForm.bsi.$invalid && !settingsForm.bsi.$pristine && settingsForm.bsi.$dirty }">
<input style="width:67px;margin:0 auto;" type="text" name="bsi" class="form-control" ng-model="SyncInterval" maxlength="4" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,4}$/" required input-tooltip></div>
```

The Tool Tip while error in the form is not visible. Any Suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And... What is the problem exactly?

Comment: it is not showing tooltip

Comment: Can you add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The problem in the above example is tooltip on form error is missing. I want to have a tooltip when there is any error on input fields of form.